# "Reply about" or "Reply to"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, grammaticality

Is *I'll reply about this later.* grammatically correct?
Does it correctly use *about*, or should it use *to*?

Comment: Please do some research before asking questions. Show what you think or have discovered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You reply **to** people and you respond **to** their messages or queries.

You can reply to them **about** a particular issue or problem or question.

More often, you would say: **Concerning your question on......**.

Yes, you could say: **I'll reply about this later**.

A more informal way would be to say: **I'll get/come back to you about this later**.